# How to set up MSDTC with Dockerized SQL Server for Linux

Tags: sql-server, linux, docker, msdtc

I am trying to use Docker Compose to set up MSDTC in a SQL Server container as described here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-configure-msdtc-docker?view=sql-server-ver15

My compose file looks like this, mirroring the command-line arguments referenced in the above document:

```yaml
services:
  pte_mssql:
    build:
      context: ./mssql/docker
    environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA: 'Y'
      MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD: '${startupSaPassword}'
      MSSQL_RPC_PORT: 135
      MSSQL_DTC_TCP_PORT: 51000
    ports:
      - 1433:1433
      - 135:135
      - 51000:51000
```

However, the DTC service does not appear to start. I see this repeated in the output (other ports seem to be OK):

```
Waiting for TCP socket on 172.24.0.1:51000 of 'pte_mssql_1' (Connection refused (Connection refused))
Will use 172.24.0.1 (network vestmarkone_default) as host of pte_mssql
More forwarded TCP ports for service 'pte_mssql:135 [[HostIp:0.0.0.0, HostPort:135], [HostIp:::, HostPort:135]]'. Will use the first one.
More forwarded TCP ports for service 'pte_mssql:1433 [[HostIp:0.0.0.0, HostPort:1433], [HostIp:::, HostPort:1433]]'. Will use the first one.
More forwarded TCP ports for service 'pte_mssql:51000 [[HostIp:0.0.0.0, HostPort:51000], [HostIp:::, HostPort:51000]]'. Will use the first one.
```

I used the following command to confirm that nothing is running on port 51000:

```
root@906e7184f6bc:/var/opt/mssql/log# lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
sqlservr   9 root   49u  IPv4 1613252      0t0  TCP *:135 (LISTEN)
sqlservr   9 root   51u  IPv6 1613254      0t0  TCP *:135 (LISTEN)
sqlservr   9 root   64u  IPv6 1617097      0t0  TCP *:1433 (LISTEN)
sqlservr   9 root  100u  IPv4 1617098      0t0  TCP *:1433 (LISTEN)
sqlservr   9 root  106u  IPv4 1629465      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:1434 (LISTEN)
sqlservr   9 root  110u  IPv4 1617101      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:1431 (LISTEN)
```

I also tried adding the following to my `Dockerfile` instead of setting the `MSSQL_DTC_TCP_PORT` environment variable:

```
RUN /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf set distributedtransaction.servertcpport 51000
```

This did not resolve the problem.

FWIW, creating the container from the command line (as shown in the article) rather than via Docker Compose produces the same results. Note that I started the container as root so I could run `lsof` to troubleshoot. I also used "2019-latest" rather than "2019-GA-ubuntu-20.04" since the latter no longer appears to exist:

```
docker run \
   -u root \
   -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=pass@1234' \
   -e 'MSSQL_RPC_PORT=135' -e 'MSSQL_DTC_TCP_PORT=51000' \
   -p 1433:1433 -p 135:135 -p 51000:51000  \
   -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
```

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to enable the DTC service, or how to troubleshoot further?

Comment: Are you running this as  regular user? Ports under `1000` are restricted so `135` would need root user (as in `sudo docker run` or `sudo docker-compose`). Also, maybe try `netstat -tunlp | grep 51000` to see if there isn't anything running on `51000` (might have been randomly assigned by docker or k8s for example)

Comment: Port 135 is working - it's 51000 that is failing. I verified that nothing at all is running on port 51000 - see the lsof output above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-configure-msdtc?view=sql-server-ver16#verify), the DTC server will not start listening until a distributed transaction has begun. Once that occurs, you should see it listening on port 51000.

Comment: Confirmed. Simply executing "begin distributed transaction" appears to be sufficient.